# Google Sheets: Importing data from another sheet into a cell if ANY value in the row matches

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

For a meal planning sheet with "complex ingredients":

Sheet1 lists available meals and general ingredients needed to make the meal.

However, for ease of entry, I want to create "complex ingredients" (like Meatballs).

So, *anywhere* in the row containing a Meal's general ingredients, if you typed "Meatballs," this would then auto-populate the components to make Meatballs in a separate cell at the end of that row.

In my spreadsheet...

**Sheet 1** Row 1, lists "MEATBALL SUBS," with these general ingredients listed from B1:L1. **D1** has "Meatballs" as listed as an ingredient.

**Sheet 1** Row 7, lists "SPAGHETTI AND MEATBALLS," with general ingredients listed from B7:N7. **F7** has "Meatballs" as an ingredient.

**Sheet2** has a single entry for "Meatballs" with its own list of "sub-ingredients" in a row.
(A1 is "Meatballs" and B1 is an cell listing ground beef, breadcrumbs, eggs, etc.)

I would like to have a formula that scans the entire row for each meal on Sheet 1, and when it encounters an Ingredient such as "Meatballs" it auto populates that in a cell designated for those types of complex ingredients.

I've tried VLOOKUP and QUERY formulas, but I can't figure out the how to scan the entire row for each meal... I can only get it to work if you make a specific column on Sheet1 for "Complex Ingredients"